# Suddenly my Ctrl + F5 doesn't work in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Suddenly my Ctrl + F5 doesn't work. It just shows a empty output window. I had tried to reset settings in tools --> import and export  and "redirect all output window...." is checked off. I had also reinstalled the program, so now I use Visual Studio 2015, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: We've been getting this question all week, uninstall Avast.

Comment: The antivirus program?

Comment: The scourge to humanity, programmers in particular.  Yes.

Comment: Thanks it worked!! Still dont know why.